# Datatable select by row range c#

Tags: c#-4.0

Does anyone know how to select datatable by row range? say if I need to pull out records in datatable from row #20 - #50.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to include rows 20 and 50, I think this will work:

```
var rows = (from r in table.AsEnumerable()
            select r).Skip(19).Take(31);
```

update:

or more succinctly:

```
var rows = table.AsEnumerable().Skip(19).Take(31);
```

Comment: This gives you an `IEnumerable<DataRow>`; should you need to get a DataTable back, you can add `.CopyToDataTable()` on the end.